# How to update quantity in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am retrieving quantity from one table it comes 1 by default from `table1` and I am inserting `table1` quantity in basket `table2` and based on column `id`. I am trying to update basket `table2` quantity, it is not responding.

*Please help me to update quantity.*

(Actually my problem is Basket table quantity comes 1 from `table1`, I am trying to insert my default quantity in basket table...in controller page in update action link, id is processing but default quantity (what I am giving) is not processing the test object...suppose I am giving default object it is updating... Please help me to solve this problem )

**Model:**

```
public class tbl_Bascket
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int Quanitity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class tbl_BascketContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet basket { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private tbl_BascketContext dbbasket = new tbl_BascketContext();

public ActionResult update(int id)
{
    tbl_Bascket test = dbbasket.basket.Find(id);

    int qty = test.Quanitity;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Bascket set Quanitity='" + qty + "' where OrderID='" + id + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    return RedirectToAction("Bascket");
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `foreach`, try a `for`-loop

Comment: for_loop also not working

Comment: What is your `Model`? It should be an `IList<TheModel>` to make the `for`-loop work

Comment: Its not clear what your trying to do. An action link is a GET method, but you seem to be needing a POST method. Are you wanting to submit the whole model or just the `ID` and `Quantity` properties, and are you wanting to submit them for just one item or for the whole collection?

Comment: This is my model                                           @model IEnumerable<Pure_Vitamins_com.Models.tbl_Bascket>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bascket";
    Layout = "~/Views/Share/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}

Comment: It is a get method based on bascket item id,quantity will change but for action link it is fire same item id quantity because object not passing to text object

Comment: Check whether data exists in the view or not and also remove the single quotes as the entity is of integer type

Comment: Why do you have a form if you not submitting the form? (you don't even have a submit button). If you want to redirect to the update method and pass the value of the textbox then you need to use javascript to dynamically create the url query string e.g. `window.location.href='update?id=1&quantity=5`, and change you action method to include an additional parameter for `quantity` (but again, its a POST not a GET!). If you are wanting to update the quantity of 1 item and stay on the page to continue updating other quantities, then you need javascript/jquery to do an AJAX post.